# swagger-js-codegen api is sending the wrong request header content-type

Tags: angularjs, swagger, swagger-2.0

So I have newly upgraded to Swagger 2 from 1.x, and am experiencing an odd issue. One of my APIs is getting an incorrect content-type injected into the header and I have no idea where from, you can see below in the SwaggerJSON, The DELETE function even says it consumes application/json, but the CURL(copied from inspect panel) for it sends 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8'. I have provided the CREATE function as a cursory example to show that otherwise the similar apis work fine. I think this is an issue with swagger-js-codegen because if I put the same request into the api-docs it works fine, or of course my Java, or somewhere somehow my content-type header is getting set, but i have no idea how or where. Am I missing something? The API acts the same whether or not my JAVA claims 'consume = "application/json"' or not.

```
Swagger JSON

{
  "/api/entities/{id}/labels": {
    "delete": {
      "consumes": [
        "application/json"
      ],
      "operationId": "deleteEntityLabel",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "default": "16_appiniteDev",
          "description": "The id of the entity to be edited",
          "in": "path",
          "name": "id",
          "required": true,
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "description": "The label/labels to be deleted",
          "in": "body",
          "name": "labels",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        }
      ],
      "produces": [
        "application/json"
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "OK",
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ResponseEntity"
          }
        },
        "204": {
          "description": "No Content"
        },
        "401": {
          "description": "Unauthorized"
        },
        "403": {
          "description": "Forbidden"
        }
      },
      "summary": "Deletes Labels for Entities",
      "tags": [
        "entity-resource"
      ]
    },
    "post": {
      "consumes": [
        "application/json"
      ],
      "operationId": "createEntityLabel",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "default": "16_appiniteDev",
          "description": "The id of the entity to be edited",
          "in": "path",
          "name": "id",
          "required": true,
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "description": "The array of labels to be set",
          "in": "body",
          "name": "labels",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        }
      ],
      "produces": [
        "application/json"
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "OK",
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ResponseEntity"
          }
        },
        "201": {
          "description": "Created"
        },
        "401": {
          "description": "Unauthorized"
        },
        "403": {
          "description": "Forbidden"
        },
        "404": {
          "description": "Not Found"
        }
      },
      "summary": "Creates Labels for Entities",
      "tags": [
        "entity-resource"
      ]
    }
  }
}

DELETE
JAVA/SPRING
    /**
     * DELETE /entities/{id}/labels -> delete labels for an entity
     *
     * @param id
     * @param labels
     * @throws ServiceException
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/entities/{id}/labels", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    @ApiOperation(value = "Deletes Labels for Entities", nickname = "deleteEntityLabel", consumes = "application/json")

    public ResponseEntity deleteLabels(
            @ApiParam(value = "The id of the entity to be edited", required = true, defaultValue = "16_appiniteDev") @PathVariable final String id,
            @ApiParam(value = "The label/labels to be deleted", required = true, defaultValue = "[\"label1\",\"label2\",\"label3\"]") @NotNull final @RequestBody String[] labels

    ) throws ServiceException {
        boolean isAppEntity = false;
        User user = userService.getUserWithAuthorities();
        String[] type = id.split("_");
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(type[0]) && !type[1].startsWith(type[0])) {
            isAppEntity = true;

        }

        entityService.deleteTags(id, labels, user, isAppEntity);
        Map<String, String> response = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        response.put(Constants.RESPONSE_ENTITY_HEADER_MESSAGE,
                "Labels deleted successfully");
        return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

CURL FROM APP
curl 'http://localhost:8080//api/entities/52_QA42/labels?cacheBuster=1472070679337' -X DELETE -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'x-auth-token: admin:1472097365429:8e6524e252e2aebb786b7738c44fe385' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'Cookie: NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY=%22en%22' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data-binary '["Bug13124"]' --compressed


CREATE
JAVA/SPRING
    /**
     * POST /entities/{id}/labels -> add labels for a non hadoop entity
     *
     * @param id
     * @param labels
     * @throws ServiceException
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/entities/{id}/labels", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    @ApiOperation(value = "Creates Labels for Entities", nickname = "createEntityLabel")
    public ResponseEntity addLabels(
            @ApiParam(value = "The id of the entity to be edited", required = true, defaultValue = "16_appiniteDev") @PathVariable final String id,
            @ApiParam(value = "The array of labels to be set", required = true, defaultValue = "[\"label1\",\"label2\",\"label3\"]") @NotNull final @RequestBody String[] labels)
            throws ServiceException {
        boolean isAppEntity = false;
        User user = userService.getUserWithAuthorities();
        String[] type = id.split("_");
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(type[0]) && !type[1].startsWith(type[0])) {
            isAppEntity = true;

        }

        entityService.addTags(id, labels, user, isAppEntity);
        Map<String, String> response = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        response.put(Constants.RESPONSE_ENTITY_HEADER_MESSAGE,
                "Labels added successfully");
        return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

CURL FROM APP
curl 'http://localhost:8080//api/entities/52_QA42/labels?cacheBuster=1472071851544' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'x-auth-token: admin:1472097365429:8e6524e252e2aebb786b7738c44fe385' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'Cookie: NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY=%22en%22' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data-binary '["test"]' --compressed
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the "app"?  Do you mean swagger-ui?  And for swagger-js-codegen, are you talking about something that is produced from the swagger-codegen project, or are you talking about swagger-js?

Comment: swagger-js-codegen is the swagger-codegen FOR swagger-js. https://github.com/wcandillon/swagger-js-codegen

Comment: @trudesign you may consider using [swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate the JS client (or API clients in Typescript, PHP, Ruby, Java, etc).

Comment: @wing328 to be honest, I couldn't understand how swagger-codegen worked, and swagger-js-codegen is an approved plugin to do the angular swagger-codegen conversion for me. I need to figure out how to get swagger-js-codegen to actually write the request content-type, it seems to ignore the 'consumes' property of the swagger json file.

Comment: @trudesign thanks for the feedback. Installing java, mvn, etc so as to use swagger codegen may be pain to non-Java developers. Another way is to use https://editor.swagger.io or generating the SDKs [online](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators). If you need further assistance, pls let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to nail down how or where it is setting that Content-Type, so I've fixed this in a brute force way: Created an interceptor to change the header content-type by force:

```
.factory('contentInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $location, localStorageService, $cookies) {
    return {
        // Add authorization token to headers
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            return config;
        }
    };
})

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('contentInterceptor');
});
```

Works like a charm, and luckily doesn't affect any other of my API's as they ALL require Application/JSON except for the multipart form ones, but those explicitly get set and aren't affected by this interceptor.

**** **UPDATE** *****

I'm a dumb dumb and didn't realize I could've just put the following in my mustache template. This is the correct answer. It takes the proper 'consumes' and 'produces' properties and ensures the right headers are being sent.

```
{{#headers}}
    options.headers['{{&name}}'] = {{&value}};
{{/headers}}
```

Comment: Note: this doesn't work as well as I thought it would. It doesn't override requests made with an $http call but still overrides swagger generated api calls. Not an optimal solution. Will update next week when I figure it out.